# How to get record on basis of MAX id else shows 0 counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to write query which shows Record against the max id now i also want to get record if its not match the MAX id

This is whats i have done so  far..

So far i m able to get record against MAX id in Laptop_ShiftDepartment but i also 
need counts if its 0 count in departments

```html
SELECT
  D.Department as Depart, 
 
 COUNT(LD.ID) AS TotalLaptops
    FROM 
    Laptop_Departments D
    left JOIN Laptop_Shift_Departments S
    ON D.ID = S.Current_Dep_ID 
    left JOIN PO_LAPTOPDETAIL LD
    ON S.Laptop_Detail_ID = LD.ID 
   
    left JOIN PO_Laptop_Master LM
    ON LM.ID = LD.Laptop_Master_ID
    left JOIN PO_PURCHASEORDER PO
    ON PO.ID = LM.PO_ID

     left JOIN Laptop_Departments cD
    ON cD.ID = ld.Dept_id
WHERE S.id in (select MAX(cSD.id) from Laptop_Shift_Departments cSD  GROUP BY cSD.Laptop_Detail_ID)
     group by  D.Department ,D.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql "CASE statement" like below

```
SELECT D.Department as Depart, 
CASE 
     when S.id in (select MAX(cSD.id) 
                   from Laptop_Shift_Departments cSD 
                   GROUP BY cSD.Laptop_Detail_ID) 
     then count(LD.ID) 
ELSE 0 
END AS TotalLaptops 
FROM Laptop_Departments D 
left JOIN Laptop_Shift_Departments S ON D.ID = S.Current_Dep_ID 
left JOIN PO_LAPTOPDETAIL LD ON S.Laptop_Detail_ID = LD.ID 
left JOIN PO_Laptop_Master LM ON LM.ID = LD.Laptop_Master_ID 
left JOIN PO_PURCHASEORDER PO ON PO.ID = LM.PO_ID 
left JOIN Laptop_Departments cD ON cD.ID = ld.Dept_id 
group by D.Department ,D.ID
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as `COUNT(*)` :-)

Comment: updated my answer, it is not optimized solution but it will give your answer as expected

Answer (score 0):

Move the `where` clause to the `from` clause an use `left join`:

```
SELECT D.Department as Depart, COUNT(LD.ID) AS TotalLaptops
FROM Laptop_Departments D left join
     Laptop_Shift_Departments S
     ON D.ID = S.Current_Dep_ID left join
     PO_LAPTOPDETAIL LD
     ON S.Laptop_Detail_ID = LD.ID left join
     PO_Laptop_Master LM
     ON LM.ID = LD.Laptop_Master_ID left join
     PO_PURCHASEORDER PO
     ON PO.ID = LM.PO_ID left join
     Laptop_Departments cD
     ON cD.ID = ld.Dept_id left join
     (select MAX(cSD.id) as maxid
      from Laptop_Shift_Departments cSD 
      GROUP BY cSD.Laptop_Detail_ID
     ) m
     ON m.maxid = s.id
group by D.Department, D.ID
```